# How can I make a Tumblr background image only for one page?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, tumblr

I would like the first page on my Tumblr website to have a background image that fills the entire screen, but for that page only...the other pages will have a white background.

[Website](http://bycorduroyblue.tumblr.com)

Please help, I have been at this for a long time..no luck!

Comment: most recent attempts: http://forum.bytesforall.com/showthread.php?t=13711

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/css-set-background-image-wont-change-for-other-pages/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the body add a wrapper (around your header, content and footer) and give it an id. set the background image of this id (e.g #page1) to whatever you like, in your case the tumblr image.

Comment: don't add the wrapper id on the other pages obviously

Comment: how can I find the ID for the homepage? It worked for blog entries (#entry), but I need it for the homepage (first page) ..... #permalink didnt work

Comment: if ( is_home() ) {  } ?

Comment: Tumblr doesn't really have a concept of differentiating between pages. Generally it is one template for all pages. There is a tag {block:IndexPage} however that is not only reserved for the home page. The only way to truly do this (I believe) is via javascript

Comment: how would i go about doing that?

Comment: or i think you can make tumblr post full screen, and only post one photo for the background, and use a separate page to upload photos for the blog?

Comment: @Goeiekarma please use the @ symbol and address the person you are talking to, otherwise everyone gets your messages

Comment: I was talking to all of you though?

Answer (score 0):

So, the way I would do it is like this:

Create a block of html with the properties that we require that we will only show in the home page:

```
<div id="entry"></div>
```

Set the css of this to contain our image inside the style tags (or external css if you are doing it that way) and set the element to `display:none` as a default:

```
#entry {
   display:none;
   background:url("path/to/image.png") center center no-repeat;
   background-size:cover;
   ...
}
```

Create a custom script which checks to see if we are on the index page and if we are show the entry element otherwise hide it:

```
var primaryDir  = document.location.href.split("/")[3]; // get the first directory
var entry = $('#entry'); // cache the #entry selector in a variable
if (!primaryDir){ // if the primary directory is empty show the entry element
   entry.show();
}else{
   entry.hide();
}
```

You might need to modify the css for the entry element, but I am sure you can do that.

I've tried to add comments to explain the code.

Answer (score 0):

How about calling on the page number via {CurrentPage} and adding it as an ID? Like this:

```
<body id="page{CurrentPage}">
```

Add CSS accordingly.

```
#page1 { background... }
```

Hope this helps.